# Attach video to marker using google map API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Desired output: attach a video to a marker

What has been achieved yet: basic google map codes to place a marker at a specific location

Idea: use the marker variable defined to attach the video

Tried using Infowindow but it doesnt show the video. Note that the video is in the same folder as the file which contains my code. Can anyone help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

   function initialize()
   {
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(-20.240154, 57.589669),
            zoom:10,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var curepipe=new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.318813, 57.524149)
});

curepipe.setMap(map);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:"Hello World!"
});

 infowindow.open(map,marker);
 }

  }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
 </head>
```

Comment: I've had succes using an iFrame as the InfoWindow's content:

<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UmFjNiiVk9w?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>!

Comment: have you just added a video to a website or the video is appended to the marker?

Comment: No, the video is just HTML that calls a different website. See the other answers for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically had everything already, just needed to add an html5 `video` element to the `InfoWindow`, also ensure your video files are accessible via your server.

Aaaand, with just a few minor changes:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.240154, 57.589669),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var curepipe = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.318813, 57.524149)
  });

  curepipe.setMap(map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<video controls="" style="width:100px;height:100px;" poster="poster.png">' +
    '<source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm;">' +
    '<source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" type="video/mp4;">' +
    '</video>'
  });

  infowindow.open(map, curepipe);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
```

**EDIT**

the video I used comes from [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) page

Comment: i wanted to award the bounty right away but it's only after 22hrs that i'l be able to!! :( thanks ALOT

Comment: this is great but is there another way it could be done without using infowindow?

Comment: the only way seems to be through overlays (of which infowindow is one) : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an iframe;

Try:

```
   function initialize() {

      var mapProp = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.240154, 57.589669),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp)
      var curepipe = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.318813, 57.524149)
      });

      curepipe.setMap(map);
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<iframe title="YouTube video player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0vrdgDdPApQ?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
      });

      infowindow.open(map, curepipe);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="googleMap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6a7onyL/4/)